# Connecting from domestic to international at Athens Airport

Tags: short-connections, connecting-flights, ath

We are traveling from Crete to Athens to catch our flight home to the US, our potential flight from Crete will land at 915am Our international flight home leaves at 12:55. Is this enough time to get to our flight, through customs. June 30 2020

Answer (score 1):

It's plenty of time.  Passport checkpoints are a little slow in Athens, but not three hours.